# Pythonで>>>のプロンプトを入れる意味とは

Tags: python, コマンドプロンプト

Pythonで

```
>>>
```

上記のプロンプトを入れる意味とはどのようなものなんでしょうか。

ある教科書に

```
>>> 12 + 22
34
```

というようなことが書かれていたのですが、これは下記の場合でも同様だと思います。何が異なるんでしょう？

```
12 + 22
34
```

Comment: その「教科書」が何かは分かりませんが、入門書であれば掲載コードの読み方についても説明がありませんか？（>>> の意味についての記述はありませんでしたか？）

Answer (score 3):

Pythonのドキュメントに説明が記載されています。
[2. Python インタプリタを使う](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/interpreter.html)
[2.1.2. 対話モード](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode)

> インタプリタが命令を端末 (tty) やコマンドプロンプトから読み取っている場合、インタプリタは 対話モード (interactive mode) で動作しているといいます。 このモードでは、インタプリタは 一次プロンプト (primary prompt) を表示して、ユーザにコマンドを入力するよう促します。一次プロンプトは普通、三つの「大なり記号」 (`>>>`) です。継続行では、インタプリタは 二次プロンプト (secondary prompt) を表示します。二次プロンプトは、デフォルトでは三つのドット (`...`) です。 インタプリタは、最初のプロンプトを出す前にバージョン番号と著作権表示から始まる起動メッセージを出力します:

上記説明内容によれば、`>>>`は`...`と併せてコマンド入力時の状態を表していると言えるでしょう。

`>>>`は初期の入力状態で、それ以前には何も入力されておらず、インデントや括弧/クォーテーション等を閉じる必要が無い基本的な状態ですね。

そしてプロンプトが`...`に変わった場合は、`if`文とか`for`文等の中でインデント入力が必要か、またはそれらの文や括弧/クォーテーション等による入力途中で文や式が完了していない状態です。

---

ちなみに`プロンプトを入れる`という表現はちょっと曖昧に見えて、操作している人間が`>>>`とキー入力する必要があるようにも取れるので、注意しましょう。

プロンプトを表示するのはPythonインタプリタが行っていることです。
教科書などそういった資料で`>>>`が記載されているのは、Pythonインタプリタが操作者に入力を促す(それがプロンプトという言葉の意味です)ために表示している状態をそのまま反映しているからでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

`>>>` は対話モードで実行していることを示してるんじゃないでしょうか。
プログラムのコードではないですよね。